# Magento- Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. Every time a user tries to login he gets this error. Tried to find solution here but was not able to find.

> Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/lib/Zend/Captcha/Base.php, line 1
>
> Trace:
>   #0 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
>   #1 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://popartfa...', 302)
>   #2 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(711): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://popartfa...')
>   #3 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(689): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('*/*/', Array)
>   #4 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(153): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('*/*/')
>   #5 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->loginPostAction()
>   #6 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('loginPost')
>   #7 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #8 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #9 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #10 /home/jerseytown/public_html/popartfactory.in/index.php(71): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #11 {main}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem some value or null value echoing before Magento start redirection after login, you have to check is there anything sending to the browser before start redirection.

Check you theme files properly, it may help.